# Linux kernel doesn't load removable device with system on it

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub, usb-storage

I'm having issue with booting into my Fedora 19. First of all I have to mention that I "extracted" that system from virtual disk (simply DD the content of root and boot partition on physical disk), so there are plenty of things that could go wrong, but this appears not to be related problem. I've used live Ubuntu distribution to `chroot` into my Fedora system, used `grub2-install` and `grub2-mkconfig` to repair any grub errors that might appear, and it did work. Grub could find all kernels in boot partition and load it up, but then the problem appeared.

I'll use few pictures to demonstrate my situation. This is the error I get when booting into fedora.

[image: Booting in]

Now this is true, as `blkid` in dracut shell gives this. Those are my partitions on SATA HDD in notebook, normally referenced as `sda`, but I had another 2 USB devices plugged in, having system on one of them. The device with system is usually `sdb` and has both `root` and `boot` partition on it, so while grub must have known about it, it doesn't show up in this stage and it appears to me as kernel wasn't able to load them.
[image: Dracut blkid]

To support the fact that those partitions really exist and are in good state, I ran live Ubuntu and called `blkid` from there. And here the partitions that are missing during booting popped up.
[image: Ubuntu blkid]

So my question is, what could be possibly wrong with that Fedora and how to fix that? As I said I can chroot from Ubuntu so I can configure anything, if needed. Also, this problems appear only when I boot the "full" kernel. There's also option in grub to boot into rescue mode that works just fine and I can see my data in home folder (which is the same partition as root) there. I also include this information that describes [my hardware configuration](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7144194).

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Fedora, but the problem appears to stem from missing access to USB Mass Storage devices. The corresponding kernel modules are probably missing from the initramfs or need to be explicitly activated.

Comment: what is the result of this:  **ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading fedora 19 to 20 through live environment. It may be the case that fedora configured differently when installed inside virtual box and that information persisted somewhere. This upgrade has kept most of the data and programs intact, therefore for someone with such option it can be "good enough" solution.

Answer (score -1):

Go into fstab and mtab and update the UUID.  Your screen capture shows that the new and old have different UUID.

Comment: Could you be, please, more specific about new and old UUID? I'm not able to see that mismatch.

Comment: I don't see any different UUIDs. In fact, the configuration is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Raven Long story short, even if you clone the new hard drive will have a different UUID.  You need to change the UUID to match the new hard drive.

Comment: @cybernard I'm aware of that, however mtab is created dynamically and fstab has correct UUIDs, so I can't really update anything because nothing's wrong there.